# Baking of Cartoon Eye

Tags: materials, baking, procedural

I'm trying to create a cartoon eye according to the video tutorial ["[2.91] Blender Tutorial: Create Animated Eyes, Beginner Tutorial"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzsUB6wHG3I). The author uses a standard *cube*, but I took a standard *UV sphere*. In this regard, two questions arose.

1. How to move the pupil and iris to the pole of the sphere in the selection? This is necessary for the convenience of UV unwrapping. *Mapping* didn't help me.
2. Where is information stored when baking a *Image Texture*? Is it a graphic file, a cache in the temporary files of the system, or some structures in the *.blend* file?
   Blender version 3.1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an *Input > Texture Coordinate*, plug its *Object* output into a *Vector > Mapping* that you plug into the *Gradient*, and rotate the *Mapping* on Z to align the pupil with the sphere pole:

[image]

You could also simply go in Edit mode, rotate the mesh so that it aligns with the pupil.

For the bake, it will be saved onto the image that you'll create in the *Image Texture* node. So you need to click on *New* to create the image, bake, and at last save the image into a file or pack it into the blend file: Open the *UV Editor*, select the image, go into the *Image* panel and *Save As* or *Pack*.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for your help!